# .NET Installer - Target Directory is empty

Tags: c#, .net, wix

We are trying to figure out why our assemblies are not being installed to the gac.  We have the Assembly attribute set to .net to specify GAC installation as defined here. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html

This is what is output to our log file -

```
InstallFiles: File: MyAssembly.dll,  Directory: ,  Size: 108544
```

Any idea why the Directory is null/empty/not set instead of being set to c:\windows\assembly?

We are looking into this because MyAssembly.dll is not being installed anywhere that the application can find it (not the local application bin or the gac).

Comment: Does it matter?  Is something not working for you?  The gac is not a directory, registration is not a file copy, registration occurs via [`IAssemblyCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231448(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: We are looking into this because MyAssembly.dll is not being installed anywhere that the application can find it (not the local application bin or the gac).  I'm wondering if Directory should be set to c:\windows\system32 or if this is a red herring.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. Have you checked if the assembly is in the gac?  Try running `gacutil /l MyAssemblyName`.  I'd also try [Fusion Logging](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to get the full name that the application is looking for, including bitness.

Comment: The assembly is not in the gac.  FusionLog didn't provide anything additionally helpful.  The issue is that the assembly is not in the gac or the bin directory after install.

Comment: I would open a new question as "Why is this file not installed into the gac", make sure to include the `wxs` file you are using.  If you add a comment referencing me (@Mitch), I will take a look. In no particular order, I would be verifying that the component is referenced in a feature selected for install, verify that the installer is set for `perMachine`, and check the produced msi with Orca.

Comment: And in clarification, can you confirm that `gacutil /l AssemblyName` prints `The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies: Number of items = 0`?

Comment: I agree with the above comments. In addiiton, if you have assemblies getting copied to the GAC, i would see an action which indicates that such a thing is happening:    ActionStart(Name=MsiPublishAssemblies  ... Do you see such an action being trigerred?

Comment: Ok, looks like the assembly is being added to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\.  I was going down a completely wrong path with trying to find our assembly issue.  Thanks for setting me back on the right path.  The initial issue, that started all this, is a "Method not found" exception that I will go back to digging into.  Thanks again for your help.